# Is there any way to make a hotkey turn the screen off?

Tags: shortcut-keys, screen, power-management, scripts

How can I make a script (or make some changes) to allow me to turn the screen off in Ubuntu (12.04) whenever I want, the way thevscreen can be turned off in Cellphones?

And how can I make a combination of keys (a shortcut) to execute that script?

I want to conserve power.

I've seen this question

[Turning Monitor Off With an Icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337642/turning-monitor-off-with-an-icon) but there is no hotkey for it.

Moreover, in the answer, it is said that there are many ways to accomplish this so I'd like to know more.

Comment: To assign custom key combination use these steps from
[Official ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off monitor by hotkeys?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/216653/how-to-turn-off-monitor-by-hotkeys)

Comment: Reversing the direction of close (voting to leave this open) as this is the better post imho

Answer (score 34):

If I understood well your question, you could use this commmand

```
xset dpms force off
```

In your settings, go to keyboard, shortcut, click on plus, write the name you want and past the command I just wrote, click on the new short cut and use the combination or key you want to use

Comment: `xset dpms force off`? :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm new here and have some problems with >
Thank you :)

Comment: Works great. When you move the mouse it comes back on.

Comment: `xset dpms force standby` seems to be more reliable and doesn't need the  `sleep 1 ; xset dpms force off` trick.

Answer (score 29):

Custom shortcuts to do this with newer versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 16.04) seems to require a delay from pressing the key combination to running the command. The simplest solution is to modify the shortcut command using `sh`.

Go to `System Settings... | Keyboard | Shortcuts | Custom Shortcuts`. Create a new custom shortcut and in `Command` put:

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.3 && xset dpms force off'
```

You can change the delay but I found *0.1s* was not quite enough sometimes.

[image]

Comment: Great! The only working solution for Debian "Jessie" 8 with Gnome environment.

Comment: Still the only one that works for me in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 12):

The command is `xset dpms force off`

Just create a keyboard shortcut for it. Go to keyboard->shortcuts....go to `custom shortcuts`.....& then click on the `+` icon to create a new shortcut.

Then assign the above & assign custom key combination.

[image]

DONE!

Answer (score 9):

At the beginning I also configured a key shortcut with

```
xset dpms force off
```

But after 2 seconds the display turned on again. Maybe my newer Ubuntu Version (15.05) is the reason for this different behaviour. The solution was to create a script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1 && xset dpms force off
```

Now call this script every time you press the shortcut.

I think this method works because of any delayed key press event. With the sleep command all key events have 1 second to be processed and they do not wake the screen up again.

Comment: Please also mention how to link the script file to the shortcut